# Testing whether two percentage changes from different datasets are statistically significantly different

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, percentage, cross-section

I have data on Male strength at 40 and 70 years, and equivalent data for Women. I can calculate the raw and % differences in strength for each sex, and of course compare the raw values to see which sex loses more strength with age in absolute terms. However, I am unsure about how to compare the % difference between the two groups. Specifically, I would like to determine whether the % difference (40-70) observed between sexes is significantly different; e.g., if 70-year-old women are 18% weaker than 40-year-old women, is this significantly different from 70-year-old men being 16% weaker than 40-year-old men?

My data are actually cross-sectional data, not longitudinal measurements of the same people. I have individual measurements, sample size, mean, St. Dev., etc. Which mathematical approach (if any) would be best for answering this question?

I predominantly work in R so any tips for R packages/commands would be particularly helpful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking at the interaction between sex and age, although I'm not too sure what it is exactly you want to compare. Perhaps I would start with a linear model to describe strength as a combination of age and sex allowing for interaction:

```
fit <- lm(strength ~ sex * age)
summary(fit)
```

(Maybe you need a generalized linear model, GLM, instead of the ordinary linear model)

The [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) package should be useful to query the fitted model for comparisons of interest.

EDIT: Start by plotting strength vs age for each sex to get a feel for how the data looks like. In R and ggplot2 it may be something like:

```
gg <- ggplot(data= dat, aes(x= age, y= strength, colour= sex)) +
    geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if this is a homework problem, so I'll just give a hint. Consider log(strength).